# Headerenricher Spring Integration and java dsl

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, dsl

I'me using Spring Integration and java dsl specifications to implement my IntegrationFlow. 
I want to use an custom header enricher to add some file names to the header, it will be something like :

```
public class FileHeaderNamingEnricher {
    public Message<File> enrichHeader(Message<File> fileMessage) {
            // getting some details fom the database ...
            return messageBuilder
                    .setHeader("filename", "somestuff")
                    .build();
        }  
}
```

And my Integration flow will look like :

```
public IntegrationFlow myflow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("input")
                                .enrich // here I want to enrich the header using my class
    }
```

Can any one help me with this please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have your `FileHeaderNamingEnricher` extend `AbstractReplyProducingMesageHandler` (put your code in `handleRequestMessage()`).

Or, implement `GenericHandler<T>` (its `handle` method gets the payload and headers as parameters and can return a message).

Then use the `.handle` method...

```
 ...
 .handle(myEnricher())
 ...

 @Bean
 public void MessageHandler myEnricher() {
    return new FileHeaderNamingEnricher();
 }
```

Comment: and how can I access payload in my FileHeaderNamingEnricher and set the header ?

Comment: `AbstractReplyProducingMesageHandler.handleRequestMessage(Message<?> message)` - the `handleRequestMessage` method gets the message and returns an object (which can also be a `Message<?>`. So exactly the code you have above.

Comment: Thank you this resolve my problem, I seen that I can also implement GenericHandler.

Comment: Yes; added that to the answer.

Comment: sir, but can't we use, .enrichHeaders() api call to put a key(string), and List<String> as the value to put it into a header?

Comment: Don't ask new questions on old answers especially ones that are 4 years old. This question was explicitly about wiring in a custom header enricher, ask a new question if you still have a problem